# Sum input integer by itself, integer times

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement, output

Salam, I'm given a user input that I have to sum it by itself n-times. Which means if the input is "5" for example, I should return `5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 25`
I used:

```
def sum(user_input):
    inp_sum = 0
    string = ''
    for n in range(0, user_input, 1):
        inp_sum += user_input
        if n != user_input -1:
            string+= "5 + "
        else: string += '5'
    return string + ' = ' + str(inp_sum)
```

but it returns

```
Failed for value=6 
Expected: 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 36
Actual: 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 36
```

what is the solution?

Comment: this logic does not make sense

Comment: how to make it make sence?

Comment: You are literally telling python with ... if n != user_input -1:  string+= "5 + "...else: string += '5'.... that no matter the input python should always return "5" as the string

Comment: I didn't get it actually @MaximilianFreitag

Answer (score 1):

You hardcoded `5` in to the logic of your function, when you should be passing in the user input to the string format logic. Also, do not name your function `sum` as you will shadow the built-in function `sum`.

```
def mysum(user_input):
    inp_sum = 0
    string = ""
    for n in range(0, user_input, 1):
        inp_sum += user_input
        if n != user_input - 1:
            string += "{} + ".format(user_input)
        else:
            string += str(user_input)
    return "{} = {}".format(string, inp_sum)
```

Comment: this returns this error: Failed to import test module: evaluate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/eval/evaluate.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sum
  File "/eval/sum.py", line 7
    string += f"{user_input} + "
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: OK you are using Python3.5 and f-string were added in Python3.6, I updated the answer to use the older format

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it like this:

```
def user_input(n):
    return "{} = {}".format(' + '.join([str(n) for _ in range(n)]), str(n*n))

print(user_input(5))
# 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 25

print(user_input(6))
# 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 36
```